# Library not found for -lSystem in GNU fortran

Tags: xcode, macos, fortran, gnu, gfortran

I am using GNU fortran compiler and I am compiling the code using command prompt in MacOS. I am getting an error which says that the 
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have tried reinstalling the xcode and it did not work

gfortran -o executable try.o

Should be getting an executable file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GFortran error: ld: library not found for -lSystem when trying to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile)