# GFortran error: ld: library not found for -lSystem when trying to compile

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am getting a strange error when trying to compile a simple fortran-90 file using gfortran. I am working on a macOS mojave system. I have gfortran 8.2.0 installed and I checked to be sure of this by doing the following:

```
Input: gfortran --version
Output: GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A 
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Which indicates that gfortran installed correctly and I also confirmed this by typing simply: gfortran, into the terminal, which returns:

```
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

However, when I try to compile my file like so:

```
gfortran hello.f90 -o hello.x
```

I get an error which reads:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried compiling in different ways and I also tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bash_profile as described by https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries32Linux but I still get the same error. The gfortran directory has the pathname: /usr/local/gfortran, however another gfortran which is not a directory can be found in /usr/local/bin

Typing:

```
which gfortran
```

Outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

And a long list search of this directory:

```
Input: ls -l /usr/local/bin/gfortran
Output: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  32 15 May 14:07 
/usr/local/bin/gfortran -> /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
```

How can I fix this where everything seems to be correctly installed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have the xcode command line tools installed? Depending on the gfortran binary, those might be needed for stuff to work. You might also want to use e.g. the homebrew builds, those are kept up to date.

Comment: @janneb I do have command line tools installed for xcode, and I tried the homebrew build on another apple setup and the same problem occurred but I can try it on this computer

Comment: Command line tools is outdated. Solution: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, then `xcode-select --install`, `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, update Xcode if it's too out-dated. After all, you might like to `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app` if you installed Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but installing gfortran build from the gcc package using homebrew did not help. Instead, I installed the whole gcc using homebrew:

`brew install gcc`

and that solved the problem.

Comment: this isn't a fix. (sure it gets you a working gfortran but doesn't answer the question)

Answer (score 26):

On macOS Big Sur v11.1:

Relevant SO post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408999/gfortran-compiler-error-on-mac-os-big-sur

The fix is to add the stdlib to your `$LIBRARY_PATH`. For some reason or another it isn't in your standard `$PATH` anymore on 11.1.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
```

(or add it to login file and restart terminal).

Comment: could you ELI5 this? what is a stdlib and a $LIBRARY_PATH? In particular, where do I run the code snippet you shared? Thanks!

Comment: > "what is a stdlib"
Around the time of Aristotle programmers thought to themselves "hmm we seem to be writing the same basic code over and over again, maybe we should standardize it". And so `stdlib` was born. It contains all the basic building blocks like memory allocation, random number generators, string to X conversion, process and system control and even some basic sort routines. It is essential for almost any program in existence.

Comment: > $LIBRARY_PATH
[Note: `$LIBRARY_PATH` is for gcc only!] Your computer is a big box of junk, and yet somehow the magic fairies working for the compiler and linker know exactly where to look for `myBoolLib.so` so that you can use `bool invertBoolean(bool in);`. How do they know where to look? You could tell them in fine grained detail exactly where to look every time you compile but that's *tedious*. So you declare what is essentially a system-wide variable that lists a bunch of places that the aforementioned fairies should look when compiling.

Comment: > "where do I run the code snippet you shared?"
From the command line, but beware you will have to do it every time. Alternatively you can put it in your "login file", which assuming you're using bash is `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.bashrc`. These are run every time you open a new terminal and serve as a sort of "customization" file. If you paste the above code in either, it will auto-magically execute whenever you create a new terminal instance.

Comment: On my Big Sur system it's actually at a slightly different path: ```export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/usr/lib"```

Comment: As in, you don't have `MacOSX.sdk` at all? Or the up to date headers are in `MacOSX11.1.sdk`? `MacOSX.sdk` should in reality be a symlink to the latest version, on my (also still big sur) system this is `MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX11.3.sdk`.

Comment: I'm not @VictorEijkhout, but I can confirm that on my system there is also no symlink  to an unversioned `MacOSX.sdk`, just the versioned directory.

Answer (score 12):

I added this to my `~/.profile`:

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$SDKROOT/usr/lib"
```

And it works.

Comment: Might be worth putting `export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$SDKROOT/usr/lib"`

Comment: Does SDKROOT need to be exported? Does it serve any purpose for build tools?

Answer (score 5):

I'll also chime in (19 Dec 2020) that I just updated from MacOS Mojave to Catalina and suddenly got this error.

It resolved itself with

```sh
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall gfortran
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: I tried what was suggested and installed the gfortran build from the gcc package using homebrew which gave me a newer version of gfortran and my problem was fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Just placed this line at the end of .zshrc:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
```

and ran my Fortran code again to compile – success! The issue with -lSystem has been solved in my macOS system.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and I'd tried lots of thing to solve the problem, but only using these "both" commands solved it:

```
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall gfortran
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using MacPorts.

```
# Installed `gcc8` and `gcc_select`
sudo port install gcc_select gcc8

# then to create "gfortran" softlink to "gfortran-mp-8"
sudo port select --set gcc gcc8

# and added to my .profile
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
```

I did `ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/` and found that Xcode had installed one SDK for Catalina and one for Big Sur.  I changed the soft link for `MacOSX.sdk` to point to the Catalina version.

Answer (score -2):

I recently had this

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
```

problem after upgrading Mac OS from v10 to v11 (Big Sur). I am using `Xcode 12.3` and I used `brew install gcc` to install `gfortran 10.2.0`. I still saw the error after trying `brew reinstall gcc`. I was able to solve the problem using:

```
brew install gfortran
```

but I do not know why this works.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. However, when I run `brew reinstall gfortran`, it simply reinstalls `gcc` 10.2.0 so the issue (`ld: library not found for -lSystem`) remains. Any suggestions?