# gfortran for mac error. ld: library not found for -lSystem

Tags: xcode, macos, fortran, gfortran

I use gfortran in Mac to compile cfd codes.
But there exists the following error(picture attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLI0w.png)

I could compile successfully with visual studio in win64.
I think there is any error in my gfortran compiler.
How can I handle it.
please help me
Thank you very much.

Comment: I install gfortran with brew install and xcode and my xcode version is 11.6

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Do not include error messages as pictures, copy and paste the text here. It is very important. After you fix that, use also tag [tag:fortran] for all questions related to Fortran.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GFortran error: ld: library not found for -lSystem when trying to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile)