# gfortran ld: library not found for -lSystem

Tags: xcode, fortran, gfortran, macos-catalina

I have installed the latest available gfortran package (together with Apple Developer Tools installed, as well as "command line developer tools") as described here:

```
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS
```

If I try to run a simple fortran code from terminal using:

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test
```

I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am running it on Catalina 10.15.7 and xCode version 12.0.1.

I have found a similar question that was solved by reinstalling xCode, but that did not help me. What do I need to do to get it working? I will be happy to add context/details to the question if it helps.

Thanks!

*Edit*

Instead of installing the gfortran package itself, I installed the whole gcc using homebrew:

```
brew install gcc
```

and that solved the problem.

Comment: We do need as much detail as possible. Otherwise it will end up like the many questions that asked the same before - without any answer.

Comment: Could you also add your solution as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile ? It would be most helpful.