# ld: library not found for -lSystem macOS Big Sur 11.1

Tags: macos, makefile, terminal, lib, macos-big-sur

I've updated my Mac and when I compile any codes by using the Makefile, I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've:

- reinstalled x-code,
- updated the gcc and Homebrew
- installed xcode command line tools

But these don't work.

This is the command I used for linking:

```
FC= gfortran 
FLAGS = -c -O3 -std=legacy 
OBJS = Mod.o Arpack.o Eigenvalue.o G.o G0.o Gauleg.o Hyper_Lin.o Lambdaval.o Fcomponent.o Triton.o Triton_YG.o 
Triton_YG: $(OBJS) 
$(FC) $(OBJS) -o Triton_YG $$MKL_FFLAGS $$MKL_LIBS –
```

Comment: So, do you build your project with custom Makefiles or it is XCode-generated? Please, show the **exact command line** used for linking.

Comment: So it is gfortran. Have you checked that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile) and the [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428700/3440745) for it?

Comment: I tried just 
(brew reinstall gcc)
But when I've tried both commands 
(brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall gfortran)
It has resolved my problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes! I've reinstall gcc and gfortran.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried these "both" commands line:

```
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall gfortran
```

And it solved my problem.