# Why my Make file doesn't compiling in Mac and display ld: library not found for -lSystem?

Tags: macos, makefile, fortran

I'm actually a beginner in coding and I have to use a code in fortran.
The code actually compiling correctly under Ubuntu but I had to change for a mac, and the code don't compiling anymore, writing the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I don't understand why...If you can give me advises...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should always show the linker command line that caused the error, not just the error message.  I'd say it's pretty clear, though, there is no library named "System" being found.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile does not help you, we will need much more specific information from you.