# Installing a package and getting error - ld: library not found for -lSystem

Tags: macos, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm trying to install a package through ifort on Mac since it requires ifort to compile and run the code and I am and getting error

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
```

I don't know if oneAPI comes with that library.

```
ifort -O3 -warn all -fpp -free -assume byterecl -heap-arrays -nogen-interface -static-intel  /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/mac/compiler/include generate_inpmat.F90 -o generate_inpmat
```

Comment: Does “system.a” or “system.so” exist in mixed case?
or lowercase?
And does it live somewhere that -I<Path> Can point to?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile  Do you have Xcode installed? How exactly did you install oneAPI?

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: I resolved the error by pointing the code to the correct library path. It seems that oneapi library now installs at the default path

Comment: @manish could you add your resolution as an answer as it may help others facing the issue

Comment: After I updated the XCode CLI tools, clearing the intermediate CMake files fixed this error for me (`rm -rf build/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this error by pointing the correct library path.
The correct path is at

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
```

In place of

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/mac/compiler/include
```