# The Fortran compiled using Visual Studio Code on Mac causes "library not found for -lSystem"

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fortran, linker-errors

I tried to compile my code in Fortran by Visual Studio. I coded an easy example.

```
program fortran
    implicit none
    character*20 :: name
    print*,"what is your name"
    read *, name
    print *,"Hello ", name
end program fortran
```

But it can't execute on my Mac terminal. The error message is: '

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also noticed that on my right bottom corner of VS, it shows `the active environment is not selected`. I guess maybe it is related to the issue?  Plus, I also downloaded the intelapi toolkit.

So what should I do now?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Did you search the error message? We have several questions and answers about this error message.

Comment: Which compiler do you have? How did you install it? How did you set it up in  VS Code?

Comment: Not quite the same but is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile of any use?