# "Unable to find -lSystem" warning when compiling with Intel Fortran using a Makefile

Tags: makefile, blas, intel-fortran

I'm trying to build a simple Fortran program using a Makefile and the Intel Fortran compiler and to link it against BLAS and LAPACK eventually. If I build the program from the command line using

`ifort xxx.f90  -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib`

then the building succeeds without issues. However, when I try the same but in a Makefile, namely

```
runme:
    ifort -c ./src/debug/main_debug.f90
    ifort -o runme *.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

The linker is not able to find the System library.

```
ipo: warning #11109: unable to find -lSystem in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ipo: warning #11109: unable to find -lpthread in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.tbd
```

This is on MacOS 12.2.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GFortran error: ld: library not found for -lSystem when trying to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156520/gfortran-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem-when-trying-to-compile)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I appended the `LIBRARY_PATH` variable by the suggested `"$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"` but now I get twice the warnings. Also, gfortran has no issue with finding the System library.

Comment: You should definitely show your Makefile.

Comment: Is the final executable created or not? What you show are just warnings. Are there also some errors?

Comment: If it runs fine on the command line but fails in a Makefile, my guess is that you have an alias for `ifort`. This alias wouldn't be called in a Makefile, but would be called by an interactive shell.

Comment: @VladimirF the final executable is indeed created. No, I only get those two warnings

Comment: @veryreverie I ran the command `alias` at the terminal and it returned nothing. The shell does initialize itself with the `setvars.sh` script that comes with the oneAPI environment.

Comment: So do those warnings actually matter for anything?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I'd prefer if there would be no warnings/errors issues upon compilation.